# Terracotta-Nodes How can I have multiple active nodes

Tags: ehcache, distributed-computing, terracotta, ehcache-bigmemory

In `Terracotta-Nodes` How can I have multiple active nodes. I am trying following commands, and I am getting only one active node and 3 mirror nodes. I am using `BigMemoryMax` Trial version.

Commands-

```
start-sample-server.bat  "terracotta" "G:\workspace\..\..\server\bin\start-tc-server.bat" -f "..\code-samples\example03-crud\tc-config-region-1.xml" -n Region1TSA
start-sample-server.bat  "terracotta" "G:\workspace\..\..\server\bin\start-tc-server.bat" -f "..\code-samples\example03-crud\tc-config-region-2.xml" -n Region2TSA
start-sample-server.bat  "terracotta" "G:\workspace\..\..\server\bin\start-tc-server.bat" -f "..\code-samples\example03-crud\tc-config-region-3.xml" -n Region3TSA
start-sample-server.bat  "terracotta" "G:\workspace\..\..\server\bin\start-tc-server.bat" -f "..\code-samples\example03-crud\tc-config-region-4.xml" -n Region4TSA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the answer was provided in terracotta-oss mailing list :

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/terracotta-oss/2wYy3OT1UAY/mZ1135UKDAAJ

Comment: To be clear, multiple active nodes is an enterprise feature of Terracotta which is not available on the open source edition.